# C# Custom Credential Provider RDP Issue

Tags: c#, credential-providers, winlogon

I am developing a C# implementation of custom credential provider.
It's working with no problems on interactive sessions. However, when i try to connect that computer with RDP (mstsc), It gives an error message after credentials are serialized. Message is:

> "An authentication error has occurred. The token supplied to the function is invalid.". In my server, GetSeralization method is like below;

```
public override int GetSerialization(out _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE pcpgsr, out _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION pcpcs, out string ppszOptionalStatusText, out _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon)
{
    pcpgsr = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE.CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED;
    pcpcs = new _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION();
    ppszOptionalStatusText = "";
    pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON.CPSI_NONE;

    var otpResult = DialogResult.Yes;

    // make OTP operation here

    if (otpResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        CredHelper.Instance.RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(out var authPackage);

        var userNameField = credentialView.GetField(FieldTypeEnum.UsernameField);
        var passwordField = credentialView.GetField(FieldTypeEnum.PasswordField);

        var userNameSplitted = userNameField.Value.SplitSpecial('\\');

        if (userNameSplitted.Count <= 1)
        {
            ppszOptionalStatusText = "Failed to pack credentials";
            pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON.CPSI_ERROR;
            return HResult.Fail;
        }

        pcpgsr = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE.CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
        pcpcs = new _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION();

        NativeLogon.KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonInit(userNameSplitted.First(), userNameSplitted.Last(), passwordField.Value, (int)usageScenario, out KerbInteractiveUnlockLogon pkiul);

        NativeLogon.KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonPack(ref pkiul, out IntPtr inCredBuffer, out int inCredSize);

        ppszOptionalStatusText = string.Empty;
        pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON.CPSI_SUCCESS;
        pcpcs.clsidCredentialProvider = Statics.CredentialProviderGuid;

        pcpcs.rgbSerialization = inCredBuffer;
        pcpcs.cbSerialization = (uint)inCredSize;
        pcpcs.ulAuthenticationPackage = authPackage;

        return HResult.Ok;
    }

    ppszOptionalStatusText = "Failed to pack credentials";
    pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON.CPSI_ERROR;
    return HResult.Fail;
}
```

My `ICredentialProviderFilter` implementation is below but I think its wrong

```
public int UpdateRemoteCredential(ref _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION pcpcsIn, out _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION pcpcsOut)
{
    pcpcsOut = pcpcsIn;

    return HResult.Ok;
}
```

I am stuck here. I cannot go forward. Thanks.

Comment: I installed my custom provider both client and server computers. My logon tile is coming while rdp credUI comes. But its not logging in. 

I also registered same credential provider in registry to credential provider filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing C++ helper library for credential pack. In CredUI scenario, Kerberos ticket was incorrect. It should be like below;

```
switch (scenario)
                {
                case 1: //CPUS_LOGON
                    pkil->MessageType = KerbInteractiveLogon;
                    hr = S_OK;
                    break;
                case 2: //CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION
                    pkil->MessageType = KerbWorkstationUnlockLogon;
                    hr = S_OK;
                    break;
                case 4: //CPUS_CREDUI
                    pkil->MessageType = KerbInteractiveLogon;
                    hr = S_OK;
                    break;
                default:
                    hr = E_FAIL;
                    break;
                }
```

Now i can connect to remote machine.